# PHP-DI: How to create interface implementation with custom constructor parameter value?

Tags: php, php-di

I'm using php-di 6.0.10

I have the interface implementation in my DI config:

\App\Writer\WriterInterface::class => DI\get(\App\Writer\Text::class)

It has constructor like this:

```
class TextWriter implements WriterInterface
 ... 
public function __construct(Settings $settings, DataConverter $dataConverter, string $filePath)
{
    $this->init($filePath);
    $this->settings = $settings;
    $this->dataConverter = $dataConverter;
}
```

In my app I want to instantiate writer with dynamic $filePath parameter:

```
$this->container->make(WriterInterface::class, ['filePath' => $this->getFilePath()]);
```

But I get this error:

> DI\Definition\Exception\InvalidDefinition: Entry "App\Writer\Text"
>   cannot be resolved: Parameter $filePath of __construct() has no value
>   defined or guessable Full definition: Object (
>       class = App\Writer\Text
>       lazy = false
>       __construct(
>           $settings = get(App\Settings)
>           $dataConverter = get(App\DataConverter)
>           $filePath = #UNDEFINED#
>       )

What is wrong? I dig into DI code and see that it handles my definition like \DI\Definition\SelfResolvingDefinition and doesn't pass the parameters to resolve() method. It works only if I explicitly specify the interface implementation - App\Writer\Text fot the make() method. But I need to have dynamic interface implementation.

How to get it working the way I want?